# Issue with conflicting Outlook Add-Ins

Tags: c#, email, outlook, add-in

We currently have a team that uses an Outlook Add-In (call it Add-In A) that we developed internally that attaches to the Send event and, if some rules around the From address and Subject are met, a form is displayed, data is written to a SQL database and the email is sent.  This works fine.

We've also just had a company-wide rollout of a third party Outlook Add-In (call it Add-In B) that checks any emails you send to see if they're going to an external address and if so asks if you're sure you want to send.  Again, this works fine.

The problem is when these two are combined.  While there's no technical problem where they conflict or anything like that, there is a potential logical error where you could try and send an email, Add-In A kicks in, the user completes the form and data gets written to the database.  Then Add-In B kicks in, warns the user they're sending an external email, they decide against sending and the whole process is cancelled.  However, the database has been updated to say it was sent, which is incorrect.

I'm struggling to think of any way to prevent this - if we could force Add-In B to fire before Add-In A then that would solve the issues, but I'm pretty sure that you can't specify the order that each Add-In should fire or be enabled, and we have no control over the code for Add-In B as it's a third party product.

Any suggestions to prevent this from being a possible outcome?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may handle the ItemAdd event of the Sent Items folder in Outlook to be sure that a mail item (Outlook Item) was sent for sure. Be aware, the Sent Items folder can be specified an runtime using the [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868473(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class.

Also you may choose the ProgID name for the add-in to make sure that your add-in is loaded after others. The events are fired in the reverse order. But all of these facts are not documented and can be changed at any time. Nobody can guarantee that it work stable all the time.